# How can I handle or test if a type is an Option in a Rust macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I am trying to create a macro to generate a struct which can be filled from a postgres-database.
Now, as there are fields in the db which are nullable and non-nullable, I'd want to handle them differently in the macro.

Output should be a struct like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub attrib_a: i64,
    pub attrib_b: Option<i64>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn get_row(&self, row: &postgres::rows::Row) -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct {
            // the non-nullable attrib_a, where I can for sure take the value out of the Option and assign it
            attrib_a: match row.get::<_, Option<i64>>("attrib_a") {
                Some(x) => x,
                None => 0,
            },

            // here for the nullable attrib_b I just want to return the Option as is
            attrib_b: row.get::<_, Option<i64>>("attrib_b"),
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the current macro code:

```rust
macro_rules! make_table_struct {
    ($tname: stmt => $sname: ident; $($fname: ident: $ftype: ty),+) => {

        #[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
        pub struct $sname {
            $(
                pub $fname: $ftype,
            )+
        }

        impl $sname
        {
            pub fn get_row(&self,row:&postgres::rows::Row)->$sname
            {
                $sname
                {
                    //How do I know if I have an Option here or not and act then accordingly?
                    $(
                        $fname: row.get::<_,Option<$ftype>>(stringify!($fname)),
                    )+
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Macro-call:

```rust
make_table_struct! ("source_table_name" => MyStruct; attrib_a: i64, attrib_b: Option<i64>)
```

Comment: You cannot. Those macros are only aware of the kind of token (expression, identifier, etc.) You cannot actually get an information that is ahead of that, like a type information. You must use another way than `Option<X>` to express the fact that `X` is optional.

Comment: Macros can distinguish between `X` and `Option<X>` on the syntactic level, but if you used another syntax like `std::option::Option<X>` or `SomeTypeAliasThatHappensToBeOption<X>` or `SomeType::SomeAssociatedTypeThatHappensToBeOption<X>` it would be wrong. Paths, type aliases and trait implementations are all resolved after macro expansion.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I do not think that it is really impossible. I think you can acchieve a (reasonably close) solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a macro that takes a `$fname` and a type, which may be optional. If the type is optional, it generates another function than if is not:

```
macro_rules! make_get_row {
    ($fname: ident, Option<$ftype: ty>) => {
        fn $fname(i: Option<$ftype>) -> i64 {
            i.unwrap_or(0)
        }
    };
    ($fname: ident, $ftype: ty) => {
        fn $fname(i: $ftype) -> i64 {
            i
        }
    };
}

make_get_row!(direct, i64);
make_get_row!(via_op, Option<i64>);

fn main() {
    direct(1);
    via_op(Some(1));
}
```

You should be able to use a (possibly adjusted) variant of this macro within `make_table_struct`.

The following is not production quality, but might lead you somewhere:

```
macro_rules! get_table_row {
    ($row: ident, nonnullable $fname:ident: $ftype:ty) => {
        $row.get::<_,$ftype>(stringify!($fname))
    };
    ($row: ident, nullable $fname:ident: $ftype:ty) => {
        match $row.get::<_,Option<Option<$ftype>>>(stringify!($fname)) { Some(x) => x, None => Some(0) }
    }
}
type nullable<T> = Option<T>;
type nonnullable<T> = T;
macro_rules! make_table_struct {
    ($tname:stmt => $sname:ident; $($nul: ident $fname:ident: $ftype:tt),+) => {

        #[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
        pub struct $sname {
            $(
                pub $fname: $nul < $ftype >,
            )+
        }

        impl $sname {
            pub fn get_row(&self, row: &postgres::rows::Row) -> $sname {
                $(
                    let $fname = get_table_row!(row, $nul $fname: $ftype);
                )+
                $sname {
                    $($fname,)+
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

make_table_struct! ("source_table_name" => MyStruct; nonnullable attrib_a: i64, nullable attrib_b: i64);
```

Comment: I had the same idea; here's as far as I got: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10bfa087ea70f39ef2acce337e24d852 The problem is that `$ftype:ty` in `make_table_struct` will not match `Option<...>`, so it needs to be `$ftype:tt` so that it can be broken down further; at least, that's my thought. I don't understand the error message. Perhaps someone with more experience writing macros can finish putting the pieces together

Comment: Yes, this is possible to match the literal `Option` token, but as @trentcl said, any other wording of the type (full path, alias, etc.) will invalidate the macro.

Comment: @trentcl I agree that it is a bit annoying to flesh out all the details, but I think it is doable (see answer).

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios You are right about this, but if the scope of all this is narrow enough, you might be able to use a solution like this.

Comment: At the OP's place, I'd use something like `attrib_b: nullable i64`.

Comment: The way you're doing it, you can (and probably should) use `$ftype:ty`. `tt` was an attempt to solve a problem that your example doesn't have because it makes `nonnullable`/`nullable` part of the syntax explicitly.